# OS X Excel 2008: Export All Document Sheets to Separate Tab Delimited Files

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, export, microsoft-excel-2008

Is it possible to bulk export multiple sheets in an Excel Document to separate tab-delimited text files? As it is, it only exports the active sheet. I've got a document with 850 sheets, all of which I'd like to get exported as tab-delimited.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805124/need-to-modify-this-export-macro-for-text-tab-delimited-output) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59075/macro-to-save-each-sheet-in-an-excel-workbook-to-separate-csv-files)

Comment: I should note I'm on OS X Excel 2008. THat one solution uses stuff with shell32.dll. We already gave that one a shot, but failed there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and simple would be something like this:

```
Public Sub ExportSheets(wbk As Workbook, sPath As String)
   Dim sht As Worksheet
   For Each sht In wbk.Worksheets
      sht.Select
      sht.SaveAs sPath & sht.Name & ".txt", XlFileFormat.xlTextMac
   Next sht
   wbk.Close
   MsgBox "Done exporting."
End Sub
```

On Windows, you would call this by typing `ExportSheets ActiveWorkbook, "C:\Data\"` in the immediate window.

Note I'm closing the workbook when done because the workbook is now the last saved text file and not the original workbook.